# Import numpy can't be resolved ERROR When I already have numpy installed

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to run my chatbot that I created with python, but I keep getting this error that I  don't have numpy installed, but I do have it installed and whenever I try to install it it tells me that it is already installed. The error reads `"ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'"`

I don't understand what the problem is, why is it always throwing this error? even for nltk and tensorflow even though I have them all installed.

How can I resolve this issue?

Here is a screen shot when i install numpy:

[image]

Here is a screen shot of the error:

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you are running the script on the same python that pip3 is installing to? I've seen this pop up on my setup when I had accidentally installed it on the wrong copy of Python.

Comment: Please select right venv, possibly your numpy is involved in different venv and you are running the app from different venv.

Comment: Actually just noticed that you are running it on Python310 and it is installing to python39.

Comment: @AlanWilliams the screenshot  of installing numpy was before i upgraded  to python310, since i  thought upgrading would   solve the  issue

Comment: @Derek could you post a new one then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by deleting a python folder that was in the root directory of C:/ which caused installing the package to be ignored and not be installed in the correct  directory which is in C:/Users/

Answer (score -1):

This is not a very correct decision, but I had same problem with another libraries. You can be using different python interpreters (in my case it was anaconda) => libraries can be installed in different folders

It was a temporarly solution, but I created new venv

```
pip install virtualenv
mkdir python-virtual-environments && cd python-virtual-environments
python3 -m venv env
source env/bin/activate    # activate venv
```

There you can install all packages for your project, and deactivate it (with ***deactivate***) command

Comment: this didnt work, got  an error when installing virtualenv and then when i cd to the python-virtual-enviroments and run python3 -m venv env it tells me Python was not found;

Comment: Are on Windows? And installed Python from www.python.org?

Comment: Looks like he is using windows in the question